# Hive :Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors, while trying to QUERY an external table in hive on nested json

Tags: json, hive

Unable to query an external hive table on a nested json due to

```
 Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
```

Json looks like-

Create table command used-

```
create external table s
(
magic String,
type String,
headers String,
messageSchemaId String,
messageSchema String,
message  struct<data:struct<s_ID:double,s_TYPE_ID:Int,NAME:String,DES   CR:String,ACTIVE_s:double,s_ID:double,s_ENABLED:Int,pharmacy_location:Int>,seData:struct<APPLICATION_ID:double,s_TYPE_ID:Int,NAME:String,DESCR:String,s_STAT:double,PROGRAM_ID:double,s_ENABLED:Int,s_location:Int>,headers:struct<operation:String, changeSequence:String, timestamp: String, streamPosition: String, transactionId: String>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
Stored as textfile
LOCATION '/user/eh2524/pt_rpt/MGPH.APPLICATION';
```

For the same json I am able to create external table with -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `MGPH_ZT`(                                  
`jsonstr` string)                                                  
PARTITIONED BY (                                                     
`dt` string)                                                       
ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                     
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'               
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                         
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                         
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'       
LOCATION                                                             
'/user/eh2524/pt_rpt/MGPH.APPLICATION/'  
TBLPROPERTIES (                                                      
'transient_lastDdlTime'='1510776187')
```

But to query the table created by above I have use jsontuple method like

```
select count(*) from pt_rpt_stg.hvf_modules j
lateral view json_tuple(j.jsonstr, 'message') m as message
lateral view json_tuple(m.message, 'data') d as datacntr
lateral view json_tuple(d.datacntr,'l_location') s as   pharmacy_location
where pharmacy_location is null;
```

I want to create the table using Json serde so that my team can query it directly like we do for a normal hive table, right now it fails when you query it.

What did I try-

- I checked if there is any /n in the json file but there was none, tried with single record as well.
- Checked the table creation definition on (https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/29814/how-to-load-nested-json-file-in-hive-table-using-h.html) for a nested json but it seems correct as i have used required complex data types.
  -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you declaring pharmacy_location as int in your table definition, but your sample data is a string: "pharmacy_location": "93". If you change that in your  table definition, it should work.

Comment: This was the issue  but i am getting the same error with the count query  `select count(*) from MGPH_APPLICATION2`

Comment: If you are able to read some records but error during the count(*). Probably you have inconsistencies between your json data. Does the stack trace  show the record ?

Comment: The issue was with the table definition only, created the table again with correct data types and it worked.